# Related Field got invalid lookup

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a Django3 project (my first) with a model named Product that has a m2m relationship with Location (ProductLocation).  ProductLocations have a m2m relationship with Category through ProductLocationCategory). I am looking to pull all products that have ProductLocation.active = True and ProductLocation.active_last_run = False.  To do so, I use the following code:

```
new_products = Product.objects.filter(locations__active=True, locations__active_last_run=False)
```

which I borrowed from the [Django help docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/).  The Product, ProductLocation, and ProductLocationCategory are as follows:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField('Location', null=True, through='ProductLocation')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)

class ProductLocation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', null=True, through='ProductLocationCategory')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
    active_last_run = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

class ProductLocationCategory(models.Model):
    product_location = models.ForeignKey('ProductLocation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
    active_last_run = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
```

The full(er) error I receive is as follows:

```
File "/home/user/projects/myproject/app/product/views.py", line 24, in location_detail
...
new_products = Product.objects.filter(locations__active=True, locations__active_last_run=False)
...
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: active_last_run
```

I have verified all the migrations have run, the fields are in the database, I have created multiple migrations adding and removing the field.  If I only run:

```
new_products = Product.objects.filter(locations__active=True)
```

then the view will complete as normal. I have searched through most of the similar questions here on SO to get where I am at now and most of the remaining topins are using something like:

```
new_products = Product.objects.filter(locations__name__icontains = 'text')
```

This will work:

```
ProductLocation.objects.filter(active_last_run=False)
```

I am sure I am missing something simple but I can't see it.  Thanks for all your help SO!

EDIT:

Added the Location model although I omitted the address fields as I didn't think they were relevant.

To add, the general structure of the data is as follows:

Product->Locations->Categories

A product can belong to multiple locations and each location can have that product in multiple categories (featured, etc..)

Comment: I'm currently not quite sure what exactly is wrong, but I think you might have to rethink certain relations between your models... Why do ProdLoc and ProdLocCat have a M2M-relation but also a FK connecting them? Is that correct? Furthermore it might be convenient to also place your location model here, does that have an 'active' attribute? Because that explains why the first one does work, will try to have a look why the second one doesn't.

Comment: No real reason.  I have been experimenting with different configurations and performance with the Django ORM.  This is also me learning ORMs.  I have been trying to get used to them.

Comment: Wait.  I think this is a case of me not understanding the ORM completely.  Where locations does ultimately point a Location, I may need to query productlocation_set instead.